# kendo UI grid - different behavior of filterable operators when disable them for one column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

As described in the documentation of kendo UI I can affect the possible filter operators with this construct:

```
 filterable: {
    operators: {
        string: {
            isempty: "Is empty",
            isnotempty: "Is not empty",
            startswith: "Starts with",
            contains: "Contains",
        }
    },
},
```

With that lines included in my columns definition, I get this four operators in the dropdown to select for filtering. But only "Is empty" works correctly. For the other three options I get no results.

If I delete these lines from the column definition of my grid I get the whole options from filterable.operators.string. When I select one of the four options, shown above, all works fine and the result is correct.

Why is there a different behavior between the default operators for a column and when disabling some of them? And how can I get the correct behavior for just the four operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `startswith` filter option first like this:

```
filterable: {
    extra: false,
    operators: {
        string: {
            startswith: "Starts with",  
            isempty: "Is empty",
            isnotempty: "Is not empty",
            contains: "Contains",
        }
    }
}
```

I did some testing with [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UmAfe) and if I didn't have `startswith` as first filter option then it would behave like you described. Otherwise it worked.